# Adding Start/Stop functionality to Auto-Refresh Code

Tags: javascript

I've been digging thru the archives and haven't found exactly what I am looking for, so since I am blocked and on a deadline, hoping someone here with more experience can help me out.

Overall team was happy with what I gave them but they are asking for start/stop button to pause the auto-refresh when they need to grab details about the ads that serve in the page. I've been hacking at it and know I am close, but can someone help me here?

Here's my code so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demand Tag Testing- Home</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  /** Function to refresh the page at specified interval. **/
  function autoRefresh(refreshPeriod) {
      setTimeout("window.location.reload();",refreshPeriod);
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
/** Function to stop refreshing the page. **/
function stopRefresh() 
{ 
clearTimeout(refreshPeriod); 
window.location.hash = 'stop' 
}
/** Function to start refreshing the page if stopped. **/
function autoRefresh(refreshPeriod) {
setTimeout("window.location.reload();",refreshPeriod);
window.location.hash = 'start' 
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="autoRefresh(60000);">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tag Tester :: Demand Partners</a>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Demand Tag Testing</h1>
    <p>This is a template for testing the tags we get from Demand Partners. It includes scripts that auto-refresh the page every 60 seconds and keeps track of the number of page views for you.  You can also manually refresh from cache or the server using the buttons below.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>There are three ad slots below, load 1 tag per slot.</li>
      <li>Allow test to run until pageview counter reaches 500</li>
      <li>The pageview counter is PER SESSION, so if you close your browser, you will lose the count</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>Ad Slot #1</h2>
      <p>Paste Ad Tags Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h2>Ad Slot #2</h2>
      <p>Paste Tags Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h2>Ad Slot #3</h2>
      <p>Paste Tags Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Page Reload Count:</h2>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
          sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.write("The page has been reloaded " + sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.");
      </script>
      <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="startRefresh()" id="start">Start Refresh</a>
          <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="stopRefresh()" id="stop">Stop Refresh</a>
          <p id="console"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Reload Cached Page:</h2>
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:window.location.reload();">Click To Reload From Cache</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Reload From Server</h2>
      <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Click To Reload From Server</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Company Name, Inc 2014</p>
  </footer>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
</body>

</html>
```

I just need help linking those start/stop buttons to my refresh code and some output that lets users know when it's toggled, so any help anyone can provide here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few issues there, first of all you don't have start function but two autoRefresh which is a typo I guess .. Second, you need to declare global variable and store the timeout in there. Here is updated code which should work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demand Tag Testing- Home</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var myRefreshTimeout;

    /** Function to refresh the page at specified interval. **/
    function startRefresh(refreshPeriod) {
        myRefreshTimeout = setTimeout("window.location.reload();",refreshPeriod);
    }

    /** Function to stop refreshing the page. **/
    function stopRefresh() {
        clearTimeout(myRefreshTimeout);
        window.location.hash = 'stop' 
    }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="startRefresh(60000);">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tag Tester :: Demand Partners</a>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Demand Tag Testing</h1>
    <p>This is a template for testing the tags we get from Demand Partners. It includes scripts that auto-refresh the page every 60 seconds and keeps track of the number of page views for you.  You can also manually refresh from cache or the server using the buttons below.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>There are three ad slots below, load 1 tag per slot.</li>
      <li>Allow test to run until pageview counter reaches 500</li>
      <li>The pageview counter is PER SESSION, so if you close your browser, you will lose the count</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>Ad Slot #1</h2>
      <p>Paste Ad Tags Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h2>Ad Slot #2</h2>
      <p>Paste Tags Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h2>Ad Slot #3</h2>
      <p>Paste Tags Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Page Reload Count:</h2>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
          sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.write("The page has been reloaded " + sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.");
      </script>
      <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="startRefresh()" id="start">Start Refresh</a>
          <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="stopRefresh()" id="stop">Stop Refresh</a>
          <p id="console"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Reload Cached Page:</h2>
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:window.location.reload();">Click To Reload From Cache</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Reload From Server</h2>
      <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Click To Reload From Server</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Company Name, Inc 2014</p>
  </footer>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
</body>

</html>
```